# How can i filter or limit my combobox display from database?

Tags: vb.net

How can i filter or limit my combobox display from "subject(database)". i dont want to addlist all from "subject" that's why Label.text ="ad" and i want combobox display only those who have "ad" on database and shouldn't display all. i would really appreciate any help.

```
conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)

        Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT subject FROM student order by username")

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)

        Dim ds As New DataSet

        da.Fill(ds)

        cmbsection.ValueMember = "subject"

        cmbsection.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        cmbsection.SelectedIndex = 0

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)

    End Try
```

Comment: What is the mean of `Label.text ="ad" `? Anyway you can use `DataView
`

Comment: the label.text="ad" should limit only the display in comboboxlist. only those who have "ad" on database should appear in combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BindingSource` with its `Filter` property set to whatever filtering criteron you have.

I believe you do not have a whole lot of data in your db. You have already filled your DataSet. Now what you should do is to bind your ComboBox with a `BindingSource` and set its `DataSource` property to your DataTable. Next set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties  to the appropriate column names. Then at runtime, you can set your `BindingSource`'s `Filter` property like this:

```
YourBindingSource.Filter = "subject LIKE '%ad%'"
```

This will show only those records in the ComboBox that have the string "ad" in their subject column.

Comment: How can i use bindingsource in combobox? i only know how to if its in datagridview.

Comment: A BindingSource is really generic enough to be bound to both DataGridView and ComboBox. All you need to do is to set your ComboBox's DataSource property to the BindingSource.

Comment: Thanks, actually im not using any binding to my codes but im trying to use bindingsource now, but is there a way to filter combobox aside from binding, like pure code...... but really thanks :)

Comment: Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT subject FROM student where subject like'"& Label.Text &"%' order by username")
i found this but still got an error "not valid for SelectedIndex' parameter name:Selectedindex"

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should limit the data coming from the database, not get all data locally and then limit it on the client. The database is designed to limit your data for you and if you limit the data at the database, you will get the data faster across the wire (network) with less bandwidth.

So, you should add it to SQL as a where clause like this:

```
Dim sSQL As String = ("SELECT subject FROM student WHERE Subject = 'ad' order by username")
```

NOTE: If you are allowing the user to supply the value, you should use paramaters on you command but since it appears you want a hardcoded value, you can do it as above.